# Dropdown list to display tables Flask/python

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, jinja2

I have an index page that looks like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Dashboard </title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Our Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css">

    <!-- Font Awesome JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


    <!--Hospitals select list-->
    <div class="dropdown">
        <label for="sel1">Select Hospital :</label>
        <br>
        <select class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3" name="hospital" style="width:240px">
            <option value="{{hospitals[0]}}" selected>{{hospitals[0]}}</option>
            {% for hospital in hospitals[1:] %}
            <option value="{{hospital}}">{{hospital}}</option>
            {%endfor%}

        </select>
    </div>

    <!--table container starts here-->
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Table1  starts here-->
        <div class="col col-md-6">
            <div id="chart">

                <script>
             var d = {{tableJSON1 | safe}};
                Plotly.newPlot('chart', d, {});


                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Table1  ends here-->
        <!--table2 starts here-->
        <div class="col col-md-6">
            <div id="tal">

                <script>
                 var tabl = {{tableJSON | safe}};
                    Plotly.newPlot('tal', tabl, {});


                </script>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--table ends here-->
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

My flask app looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import dash_backend

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    hosp_list = dash_backend.hosp_list
    tablejson = dash_backend.admin_diagJson
    tablejson1=dash_backend.disch_diagJson
  

    return render_template('index.html', hospitals=hosp_list,tableJSON=tablejson, tableJSON1=tablejson1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Now the table I want to display on html have a column named *hospital* and the select dropdown list displays a list of hospitals. I did like assistance on how I can display tables after the hospital has been selected from dropdown list. Basically the page to remain empty until a hospital has been selected from dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to show data about a hospital in a HTML table after the hospital has been chosen from a list.

With jinja2 it's no possible to make dynamic page, so you have to implement an endpoint that accepts "hospital" as a parameter and that once called, returns the data you need to display in the table.

Add to your **select** object the **onchange** event (see more here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp), when it is triggered make ajax http request to your server at the endpoint implemented, when you recive the response update the table with the http request result.

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange="update_html_table()">
  <option value="value_1">1</option>
  <option value="value_2">2</option>
  <option value="value_3">3</option>
</select>
```

```
<script>
function update_html_table(){
      $.ajax({
        url: "https://your_server/your_new_endpoint?hospital=" + document.getElementById("mySelect").value,
        type: "get"
        success: function(response) {
            render_html_table(response);
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
          //Do Something to handle error
        }
      });
    }

function render_html_table(data) {
  //remove old row from your html table
  $("#your-table-id").empty();
  //cycle your json response and with jquery add element to your html table
  // https://www.js-tutorials.com/jquery-tutorials/dynamically-add-remove-rows-table-using-jquery/
}
</script>
```

Comment: being that I am working locally, what would be the url for the *update_html_table* function? I use path to my app.py file?

Comment: you have to specify the ip address of the computer hosting your flask application. Even if you are working locally, I recommend that you use the ip address of your pc and not localhost